# How to pass SetState variable to child component so that it changes when it changes in the parent

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I tried to make the simplest example of this here.  When you check the box, the parent text Text #1 alternates back and forth from "true" to "false" while the child text Text #2 never changes.  I want Text #2 to change just like Text #1 does.

```
function Parent(props) {
    const [state1, setState1] = useState(true);
    const [currentView, setCurrentView] = useState(<Child checkHandler={checkHandler} state1={state1} />);
    function checkHandler(event) {
        setState1(event.target.checked);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            Text #1: {state1 ? "true" : "false"}
            {currentView}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Parent;

function Child({
    state1,
    checkHandler
}) {
return (
    <div>
        Text #2: {state1 ? "true" : "false"}
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onChange={checkHandler} />
            <label for="checkbox">Check</label>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child;
```

I've searched for similar answers, but I can't find anywhere a simple explanation on how to do what I think would be a very fundamental thing to do in React Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component instances should almost never be put into state, because then their props and own state won't update naturally. You need to be calling `<Child checkHandler={checkHandler} state1={state1} /` whenever the parent re-renders so that when the parent values change, the child can re-render with its new props.

The checkbox is also not checked by default, yet you do `const [state1, setState1] = React.useState(true);` - better to be consistent. Consider adding the `checked` prop to the child.

```js
function Parent(props) {
    const [state1, setState1] = React.useState(true);
    function checkHandler(event) {
        setState1(event.target.checked);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            Text #1: {state1 ? "true" : "false"}
            <Child checkHandler={checkHandler} state1={state1} />
        </div>
    );
}

function Child({
    state1,
    checkHandler
}) {
return (
    <div>
        Text #2: {state1 ? "true" : "false"}
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onChange={checkHandler} checked={state1} />
            <label htmlFor="checkbox">Check</label>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<Parent />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly correct, a great explanation, and also helped me figure out how to default the checkbox to a SetState value.

Answer (score 1):

No need to put the entire component into the state -- it won't work either. Just give the state variable as a prop to the child.

```
function Parent(props) {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(true);
  function checkHandler(event) {
    setState1(event.target.checked);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      Text #1: {state1 ? "true" : "false"}
      <Child checkHandler={checkHandler} state1={state1} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Parent;

function Child({ state1, checkHandler }) {
  return (
    <div>
      Text #2: {state1 ? "true" : "false"}
      <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onChange={checkHandler} />
        <label for="checkbox">Check</label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child;
```