# React functional component sharing useStates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have 3 files. App.js main, uses the two components. Selector.js component, sets value. Display.js component, takes value and displays it.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Selector from './components/Selector/Selector'
import Display from './components/Display/Display'

export default function App(){
  const [myTitle, setMyTitle] = useState('test')
// Select has: code that uses setMyTitle to selected value from a list
// Display should: re-render when myTitle changes
  return(
    <div>
      <Selector />
      <Display title={myTitle} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

How do I change the value of myTitle in Selector, and use myTitle with Display (and re-render/update the display component on value change of myTitle)

Comment: pass `setMyTitle` down to `Selector` as a prop

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As @RobinZigmond said, path setMyTitle down to Selector as a prop and when changing the value of the selector, use your prop representing setMyTitle to change the value of myTitle, when you do this, state change will be triggered in the parent component and it will rerender passing the new value of myTitle to the Display Component. You can see plenty of such examples, [here's a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74579330/how-to-pass-setstate-variable-to-child-component-so-that-it-changes-when-it-chan)

Comment: @AlexWayne Sorry about that, I edited it now. Previously I had some issue posting the actual code, there was an error due to formatting and I couldn't figure out what was causing the issue.